# Automapper add logging to Map method

Tags: .net, logging, automapper, nlog

**Is there any possibility to add logging (like `nlog`) to `automapper` map method ?**

I will really want to have logged info about all mappings between objects.

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the BeforeMap event:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<SourceType, DestinationType>().BeforeMap((src, dst) =>
{
     SomeStaticLogger.DebugFormat("Mapping stuff from {0} to {1}", src, dst);
});
```